# Why does using exponentation operator ** usage produce error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

I've tried running node.js script with fragment:

```js
const max = 2 ** 16;
```

and I ended up with error:

```
const max = 2 ** 8;
               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

I imply that node.js should support [exponent operator (`**`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)), because according to [Node.js main page](https://nodejs.org/en/):

> Node.js® is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine.

I also know, that there is built-in [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) function, which does the job, however airbnb eslint style guide [recommends](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#es2016-properties--exponentiation-operator) using [exponent operator (`**`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)):

> Use exponentiation operator `**` when calculating exponentiations.
>   eslint: [no-restricted-properties](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-properties).
>
> ```
> // bad
> const binary = Math.pow(2, 10);
>
> // good
> const binary = 2 ** 10;
> ```

Therefore I imply, that using *exponentiation operator `**`* may be system / installation of Node.js problem.

---

If it's relevant - I'm using Node.js `v6.11.2` on Raspbian (`armv7l`)

Comment: Requires `--harmony` flag -> http://node.green/#ES2016-features-exponentiation------operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node.js supports the exponentiation operator since v6.7. But it requires the `--harmony` flag. Beginning with v7 the operator works out of the box.

http://node.green/#ES2016-features-exponentiation------operator